# dotnet core 3.1 application initialisation with heathcheck

Tags: .net-core

I have dotnet core 3.1 web application deployed on kubertenes and we would like to initialize application on 'health/ready' with healthcheck. Currently when i run the application it takes over 1s for application initialisation on first request to home controller.

```
[18:50:55 INF] HTTP GET /health/live responded 200 in 114.6692 ms
[18:51:13 INF] HTTP GET /health/ready responded 200 in 6.3631 ms

[18:51:43 INF] HTTP GET / responded 302 in 1052.4785 ms
[18:51:53 INF] HTTP GET / responded 302 in 5.9961 ms
```

I have added `HealthCheck()` in the startup but is there a way to send a request to home controller and warm on `health/ready` so when we real request to home controller it is finishes in 5ms instead 1000ms.

`ConfigureServices()`

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddCheck("Liveness", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy())
        .AddCheck("Readiness", () => HealthCheckResult.Healthy(), tags: new[] { "Readiness" });
```

`Configure()`

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/live", new HealthCheckOptions() {
        Predicate = r => r.Name == "Liveness"
    });

    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/ready", new HealthCheckOptions() {
        Predicate = r => r.Name == "Readiness"
    });                

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what your `HomeController` is doing that causes the initial delay?

Comment: As I understand it, dotnet core webapps do a fair amount by reflection on startup, such as figuring out dependency injection. And, from what I’ve seen, some of that is just-in-time. So the very first call to any controller is likely to cost some warmup time. I know v little about kubernetes, but can it be set up to either wait, or use let’s say the best of 3 consecutive health calls to decide whether your app is running?

Comment: @mrblewog as you can see from logs above health calls are returned within 6ms. Kubernetes is happy as both health return 200 Ok but what I am trying is to address the delay on first request. I wanted to warmup to be done in health/ready call. I understand kubernetes will only send request to container it has got success response from ready call.

Comment: The *second* health calls are quick, yes. I think this is a decent question and I have upvoted it, but as I say there does seem to be something in the way dotnet core loads whatever it needs for the *first* calls. I have  always seen the same pattern: slow first, quick subsequently.